# Export and import doesn´t work in Node.js

Tags: node.js, import, module, export

i have a problem with my export from a webscraper and the import in the app.js. I am calling the percenttage function from a ticker function. So I don't think I can return it. i want to override the variable roundedpercent and export this current value. However, only 0 is always output, even if the web scraper has been started and is no longer at 0%.

this is my current code:

trader-german.js

```
async function starttrger(){
//...
    function ticker() {
        if (scraped == lastIndex) {
            percentage(scraped, lastIndex);
            //...
        } else {
            percentage(scraped, lastIndex);
    }
}

var percent = 0;
var roundedpercent = 0;
function percentage(scraped, lastIndex){
    percent = scraped * 100 / lastIndex
    roundedpercent = Math.round(percent)
    console.log(roundedpercent) // this works correctly
}

module.exports = {
    starttrger,
    roundedpercent
}
```

this is my code in the app.js:

```
const { starttrger,roundedpercent} = require('./trader-german');
app.post('/starttrger', async(req, res) => {
    await starttrger();
    res.send({ message: 'Webscraper for trader-german started'});
});
function logProgress() {
    console.log(current Progress: ${roundedpercent}%);
}
setInterval(logProgress, 1000);
```

the console.log in the trader-german.js log out correctly the current percentage.
the console.log in the app.js log out everytime 0 and i don´t know why. Can someone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ES6 syntax, you need to make sure that your Node.js version supports it (ES6 was introduced in Node.js v4.0.0).

Comment: i have the newest node.js version. it should be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Value of the variable `roundedpercent` gets it's const value when you are importing it at `const { starttrger,roundedpercent} = require('./trader-german');`, that's why it stays the same through the app.js.

Try to make new getter function in trader-german.js called getRoundedpercent and access the variable via the function.

```
function getRoundedpercent(){
  return roundedpercent;
}
```

export it:

```
module.exports = {
    starttrger,
    getRoundedpercent
}
```

And then import it at app.js:

```
const { starttrger,getRoundedpercent} = require('./trader-german');
```

and use it:

```
function logProgress() {
    console.log(current Progress: ${getRoundedpercent}%);
}
```

Comment: @HannesZ Glad I was able to help. If my solution works for you, can you flag it as accepted? Thanks.